# Node.js/Express.js GET request in Chunks

Tags: node.js, json, express, http, iot

I am making a GET request on a Node.js/Express.js back end which contains 80KB of data. However, the IoT board I am using, that makes the GET request, has a RAM of 32KB and lags when I try to parse this large amount of data. To go around this, dividing data into chunks (8KB) and making multiple GET requests for each chunk can fix my problem. I am not sure how should I make a method that allows the data to be chunked and send via multiple get methods. I'd appreciate if someone can share their take on this. Regards!

Comment: You can stream your data and then send chunks of it instead of sending all data at once.

Answer (score 0):

Hey i'm not sure but i think this package will help you.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/JSONStream

it has a api like this.You can play with it .

```
var request = require('request');
var JSONStream = require('JSONStream')
var es = require('event-stream')

request({url: 'http://isaacs.couchone.com/registry/_all_docs'})
  .pipe(JSONStream.parse('rows.*'))
  .pipe(es.mapSync(function (data) {
    console.error(data)
    return data
  }))
```

Comment: Thank you but I am not requesting data to my Nojde.js back end I am making data available for my IoT board by making a GET method in my Node.js back end.